# jQuery highlighting all searched elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight search terms but it doesn't split the words. Two words take as a one string and highlights only the string as is.

In the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eayan/12/) you can see that "Windows XP" is highlighted but not "Windows". What should I do so the both words are highlighted?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var term = $('#q').val();
          $('p,a').highlight(term);

});
```

Comment: Yeah... we can not see it in the demo...

Comment: Instead of asking the same broken question again, you should try to fix your initial question and read the answers again.

Comment: [Looks fine to me](http://jsfiddle.net/hUyv3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this, this will split on all whitespaces

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var term = $('#q').val().split(/\s+/);
     $('p,a').highlight(term);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eayan/13/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var term = $('#q').val();
     splitTerm = term.split(" ");
     $(splitTerm ).each(function(){
          $('p,a').highlight(term);
     });               
});
```